# TableSorterPager counter reset after sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I use tablesorter for most of my data. It works well but I get a weird behaviour with the tablesorterPager plugin.

When the table is created and tablesorter is called, the pager displays correct informations and I can navigate through the different pages.
But when I use the sort feature (useful when you use a sorter :-) ), the pager tells me that there is only one page, and I'm not able to see the other pages.

Here is the JS code I use. I compared with the official documentation and almost everything I found on the web and I can't really see differences that can explains this behaviour.

```
$("#tlisting").tablesorter({

        headers: {
            2: {sorter: 'nom'},
            3: {sorter: 'date'},
            0: {sorter: false},
            6: {sorter: false},
            7: {sorter: false}
        }, debug: true 
    }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});

    var sorting = [[3, 1]];
    if ($("#tlisting tbody tr.ni_tr").length > 0) {
        $("#tlisting").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
    }

    $("#tlisting").trigger("update").trigger("appendCache").trigger("applyWidgets");
```

And here is the debug output :

```
Building cache for 20 rows:,1ms
Evaling expression:var sortWrapper = function(a,b) {var e0 = (a[2] == b[2] ? 0 : (a[2] === null ? Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY : (b[2] === null ? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : (a[2] < b[2]) ? -1 : 1 )));if(e0) { return e0; } else { return a[8]-b[8];}; return 0; }; ,0ms 
Sorting on 2,0 and dir 0 time:,1ms
Rebuilt table:,2ms
```

Thank you in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the original tablesorter (http://tablesorter.com). Don't trigger an `appendCache` after an `update`, especially with the pager plugin.

The `appendCache` method adds all table rows back into the table. So for example, if you wanted to add a row or rows to a table, with the pager initialized, you would do the following:

```
$('table')
    .trigger('appendCache')
    .append( $myNewRows )
    .trigger('update')
    .trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
```

Might I suggest you check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (don't forget to update the pager too). You shouldn't need to make any changes to your initialization code. And if you need to add a row or rows to the table, you can use the [`addRows` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addrows):

```
var $row = $('<tr>...</tr>'),
    resort = true, // resort the table using the current sort
    callback = function(table){
        console.log('rows added', $row);
    };

$('table')
    .find('tbody').append($row)
    .trigger('addRows', [$row, resort, callback]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the original tablesorter by yours. I just need to check my translations but the pager and the sorting is all good (even my row deletion and addition :-) )